# Multi-languages in amsbook using texstudio on Mac

Tags: languages, french, chinese

I'm using the following LaTeX codes in texstudio on MacBook Pro (I omit somethings):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter

\title{\textsc{AAAZZZ}}
\author{LZ}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
The goal of this book is to describe the theories from A to Z, \ldots

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I offer my sincerest gratitude to my left shoulder and right arm, \ldots

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Preliminaries on A}

\chapter{Results on Z}

\appendix

\chapter{More results on Z}

\backmatter

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I want to use some Chinese and French and possible other languages (e.g. Vietnamese) with accents (in the English text), like "九转罗汉掌，乾坤大挪移，马克撕魔鬼，étale à la P. A. Østvær, Hölder et Ngô Bảo Châu" in the text by typing directly from keyboard (rather than using \'etale etc. each time, because I use that quite often). Is there an easy way to use these languages simultaneously by add a few lines of codes in the above?

Comment: The easiest way is, I think, with XeTeX or LuaTeX. See https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/Useful-links-to-tex.stackexchange .

Comment: Thanks! I use some of them there now, but don't work in texstudio on Mac. Should I use some other thing to compile?